# Has the name "White Portuguese" a deeper meaning?

Tags: analysis, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

In the movie *Batman v Superman* "White Portuguese" is the name of a ship used for smuggling. Does the name have a special meaning?

I know of the *White Fleet*, the [Portuguese cod fishing fleet operating in the North Atlantic](http://www.santamariamanuela.pt/en/smm/white+fleet), getting the name from either painting the hulls white during World War II or from having white hulls traditionally (depending on source). Does the name refer to this? Is there any deeper meaning or is the name random except for the ambiguity needed as plot device (mistaken as a reference to a person)?

Answer (score 1):

White Portuguese doesn't seems like any reference to anything but a conversation raised between Alfred and Bruce due to it did refer to [Batman: Mask of the Phantasm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Mask_of_the_Phantasm)

> Early in the movie Alfred and Bruce are investigating a criminal they
>   can only identify as the White Portuguese. Bruce insists they need to
>   catch him, which prompts Alfred to suggest that the unknown “phantasm”
>   they’re searching for might be a woman. This is a reference to the
>   1993 film Batman: Mask of the Phantasm, where the film’s titular
>   villain is eventually revealed to be Bruce’s former love, Andrea
>   Beaumont. - [buttonmasherto.com](https://buttonmasherto.com/2016/03/25/easter-eggs-you-missed-in-batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice/)